# Prove that the following are equivalent for sets A, B and C

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I don't know how to prove that the following are equivalent for all sets A, B and C:

- $A\cup B = U$
- $\bar{A}\cap\bar{B} = \emptyset$
- $\bar{A}\subseteq B$

The bar above letters mean complement.

where $U$ is a universal set.

Can someone please show me how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: So I know that:
- A̅∩B̅ = (A∪B) complement
- A∪B = U (x∈U or y∈U)
- if A∪B = U then A¯⊆B
but I don't know how to connect all these things together into meaningful proof

Comment: I think the question you mean to ask concerns "for all subsets $A,B$, of some set $U$", and complements are taken with respect to $U$. There is no set that contains _all_ sets $A,B,C$, and no universal complementing operation.

Answer (score 0):

With simple introductory proofs on sets like these, you can probably get away with just preforming operations on one equation to get it into another form.

For example, to go from 1 to 2, it would look something like this.

We have that $A \cup B = U$.  Applying the negation law to each side yields $\neg A \cap \neg B = \emptyset$.  Thus, $A \cup B = U \implies \neg A \cap \neg B = \emptyset$

You can do something very similar for $2 \implies 3$ and $3 \implies 1$

Comment: I understand your approach but I think, that I need to show something like 1. statement ⇒ 2.statement ⇒ 3. statement ⇒ 1. statement to show that all these three are equivalent.

Comment: This would only work to show the first bullet point, given either of the others. But yes, it's OK advice.

Comment: You know what, you're absolutely right.  I read it as prove each of these sets is equal to the other, not one statement implies the other.

Comment: I'm just not sure right now. Is the negation and complement the same? Because the bars above letters mean complement of that set.